# SSIS XML source error while loading data to oledb destination, occurs occasionally

Tags: xml, ssis

Getting below error while loading the data to oledb destination from xml source using .xslt xsd file.
Error doesn't occur consistently but occurs at least once in thrice of execution, especially when trying to load 3 tables or more at at time.

Version: Microsoft Visual Studio Data Tools 2015

`Detailed Error:

```
The XML Source was unable to process the XML data. An unexpected network error occurred.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on XML Source returned error code 0xC02092AF.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().`
```

[image]